# javascript matrix manipulation is not working

Tags: javascript, regex, matrix

This is a bad coded solution to a problem in "advent of code": [link to problem](http://adventofcode.com/day/6)

I don't know the reason because my code is not working properly, I had an error related to regular expressions cause I didn't reset the pointer of the regexp object, now that error is fixed I think, but something is escaping to my knowledge in what I've done bad.

The problem is that the solution that my code displays is not correct, you can submit a solution on the link I've provided and get feedback of your solutions.

Correct solution: 543903
Given solution: 418954

```
// day 6 of advent of code

var input = "removed, take from problem";

function processInput(input, matrix) {
  var linesOfInput = input.split("\n");
  var matches;
  var turnOnRE = /turn on (\d+),(\d+).*?(\d+),(\d+)/g;
  var turnOffRE = /turn off (\d+),(\d+).*?(\d+),(\d+)/g;
  var toggleRE = /toggle (\d+),(\d+).*?(\d+),(\d+)/g;

  // regular expression objects lastIndex property must be 'reseted' in order to work well
  for (var i = 0 ; i < linesOfInput.length; i++) {
    turnOnRE.lastIndex = 0;
    turnOffRE.lastIndex = 0;
    toggleRE.lastIndex = 0;
    matches = turnOnRE.exec(linesOfInput[i]);
    if (matches != null) {
      manipulateLights(matrix, matches[1], matches[2], matches[3], matches[4], true);
      continue;
    }
    matches = turnOffRE.exec(linesOfInput[i]);
    if (matches != null) {
      manipulateLights(matrix, matches[1], matches[2], matches[3], matches[4], false);
      continue;
    }
    matches = toggleRE.exec(linesOfInput[i]);
    manipulateLights(matrix, matches[1], matches[2], matches[3], matches[4]);
  }

}

function manipulateLights(matrix, startI, startJ, endI, endJ, newValue) {
  if (newValue == undefined) { // toogle
    for (var i = startI ; i <= endI; i++) {
      for (var j = startJ ; j <= endJ; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = !matrix[i][j];
      }
    }
    console.log(startI, startJ, endI, endJ, newValue);
  } else {
    for (var i = startI ; i <= endI; i++) {
      for (var j = startJ ; j <= endJ; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = newValue;
      }
    }
    console.log(startI, startJ, endI, endJ, newValue);
  }
  console.log(countTurnedOnLights(matrix));
}

function countTurnedOnLights(matrix) {
  var turnedOn = 0;

  for (var i = 0 ; i < matrixWidth; i++) {
    for (var j = 0 ; j < matrixHeigth; j++) {
      if (matrix[i][j] == true) {
        turnedOn++;
      }
    }
  }

  return turnedOn;
}

var matrixHeigth = 1000;
var matrixWidth = 1000;

// define a bidimensional array, is almost like in C++
var lightMatrix = new Array(matrixWidth);
for (var i = 0 ; i < matrixWidth; i++) {
  lightMatrix[i] = new Array(matrixHeigth);
}

// turn off all lights
for (var i = 0 ; i < matrixWidth; i++) {
  for (var j = 0 ; j < matrixHeigth; j++) {
    lightMatrix[i][j] = false;
  }
}

processInput(input, lightMatrix);
console.log(countTurnedOnLights(lightMatrix));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I figured out the error - your regular expression matches are being treated as strings when you first create your for loops.

```
for (var i = startI ; i <= endI; i++) {
    for (var j = startJ ; j <= endJ; j++) {
```

When you hit a combo like 756,53 through 923,339, it thinks 53 > 339 and it exits the loop immediately. Either wrap each "start" variable with Number() in your for loops, or do so when passing the parameters.